# java формат даты из строки

Tags: java

Есть даты след. формата:

```
 06.07.2004 16:09:38
```

Нужно получить след. формат:

```
Y-m-d h:i:s
```

пробовал SimpleDateFormat, но видимо входящий формат не подходит по шаблону

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример конвертации из одного формата в другой:

```
String format = "dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
String newFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss";

String dateString = "06.07.2004 16:09:38";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
simpleDateFormat.applyPattern(newFormat);
newDateString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

Теперь в `newDateString` содержится `"2004-09-06 16:09:38"`.